# Yandex AJAX crawling

Tags: ajax

For AJAX crawling of Googlebot I use "_escaped_fragment_" argument in my website.
Now I checked Yandex's search results for my site.
I saw that AJAX reponses don't exist in search results.
Is there an option for Yandex like "_escaped_fragment_" ?

Else, should I check user agent and if user agent includes "YandexBot" then serve non-AJAX page?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out that Yandex also supports [Google's proposition for AJAX crawling](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started).
No need to change any code if you optimized your site for Googlebot crawling.

Comment: There is one thing that requires special treatment if you are using `<meta name="fragment" content="!">`. From Yandex docs: "the robot will index the page’s HTML version at the address `http://www.example.ru/blog?_escaped_fragment_=`
You should not place the meta tag in the HTML version of the document. If you do so, the page will not be indexed." This is different from Google.